# can not change the source image of an image component using image.sprite

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class inventorySlot : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Sprite icon;
    public Image image;
    

    public void AssignImage( itemInstance _item ) {
        
        icon = _item.source_itemData.icon;
        image.sprite = icon;
    }

}
```

I am coding an inventory system, when I update my inventory I call this method you see there. I looked to the inspector and saw that icon has been assigned, but however the sprite doesnt change. it stays the same

Comment: if `image` is the correct reference and you see `icon` being assigned correctly .. then the only option would be that something else (other code, animator etc) is overwriting the `image.sprite` afterwards ...

Comment: I solved the problem, but I dont know how to delete this question lol